# OpenMPI v1.X vs v2.X - What are the main differences?

Tags: mpi, openmpi, message-passing, multiple-versions

Many systems (e.g. Google Cloud Compute instances) come pre-installed with OpenMPI v1.X.
Since v2.X has been out for a while, is it always preferable to upgrade and use that instead? What are the main differences? Is there a difference in general performance and stability? I have been looking for this information everywhere but besides the detailed and incremental change lists I can't find a general overview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly adding MPI-3 features, deprecating support for older systems, and better support for MPI-IO (moved from ROMIO to OMPIO).

More info is available in [these slides](https://www.open-mpi.org/papers/sc-2014/Open-MPI-SC14-BOF.pdf) presented at the Supercomputing 2014 conference.